# How to call google.apis.dialogflow.v2 in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, dialogflow-es

I am new to Google APIs. I want to know how to call Google Dialogflow API in C# to get intent form the input text. But I can't find any example to call Dialogflow using C#.

Please provide some example to call Dialogflow from C#.

Comment: you can go through these links   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet and https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-dotnet-client

Comment: If you got this working, would you mind sharing some piece of code?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly you want to call the DialogFlow API from within a C# application (rather than writing fulfillment endpoint(s) that are called from DialogFlow.  If that's the case here's a sample for making that call:

```
using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2;

...
...

var query = new QueryInput
{
    Text = new TextInput
    {
        Text = "Something you want to ask a DF agent",
        LanguageCode = "en-us"
    }
};

var sessionId = "SomeUniqueId";
var agent = "MyAgentName";
var creds = GoogleCredential.FromJson("{ json google credentials file)");
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(SessionsClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, 
              creds.ToChannelCredentials());

var client = SessionsClient.Create(channel);

var dialogFlow = client.DetectIntent(
    new SessionName(agent, sessionId),
    query
);
channel.ShutdownAsync();
```

In an earlier version of the DialogFlowAPI I was running into file locking issues when trying to re-deploy a web api project which the `channel.ShutDownAsync()` seemed to solve.  I think this has been fixed in a recent release.

This is the simplest version of a DF request I've used. There is a more complicated version that passes in an input context in this post: 
[Making DialogFlow v2 DetectIntent Calls w/ C# (including input context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083499/making-dialogflow-v2-detectintent-calls-w-c-sharp-including-input-context)

Answer (score 5):

(*Nitpicking: I assume you know DialogFlow will call your code as specified/registered in the action at DialogFlow?  So your code can only respond to DialogFlow, and not call it.*)

Short answer/redirect:
Don't use Google.**Apis**.Dialogflow.v2 (with `GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookRequest` and `GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse`) but use Google.**Cloud**.Dialogflow.v2 (with `WebhookRequest` and `WebhookResponse`) - see this [eTag-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242125/google-assistant-dialogflow-api-v2-webhook-etag-error/50860403#50860403).  I will also mention some other alternatives underneath.

## Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.v2

Using [Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.v2 NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.v2/) (*Edit*: FWIW: this code was written for the beta-preview):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public dynamic PostWithCloudResponse([FromBody] WebhookRequest dialogflowRequest)
    {
        var intentName = dialogflowRequest.QueryResult.Intent.DisplayName;
        var actualQuestion = dialogflowRequest.QueryResult.QueryText;
        var testAnswer = $"Dialogflow Request for intent '{intentName}' and question '{actualQuestion}'";
        var dialogflowResponse = new WebhookResponse
        {
            FulfillmentText = testAnswer,
            FulfillmentMessages =
                { new Intent.Types.Message
                    { SimpleResponses = new Intent.Types.Message.Types.SimpleResponses
                        { SimpleResponses_ =
                            { new Intent.Types.Message.Types.SimpleResponse
                                {
                                   DisplayText = testAnswer,
                                   TextToSpeech = testAnswer,
                                   //Ssml = $"<speak>{testAnswer}</speak>"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        };
        var jsonResponse = dialogflowResponse.ToString();
        return new ContentResult { Content = jsonResponse, ContentType = "application/json" }; ;
    }
```

*Edit*: It turns out that the model binding may not bind all properties from the 'ProtoBuf-json' correctly (e.g. `WebhookRequest.outputContexts[N].parameters`), 
so one should probably use the `Google.Protobuf.JsonParser` (e.g. see [this documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/index.html#implementing-a-web-hook)).

This parser may trip over unknown fields, so one probably also wants to ignore that.  So now I use this code (I may one day make the generic method more generic and thus useful, by making `HttpContext.Request.InputStream` a parameter):

```
    public ActionResult PostWithCloudResponse()
    {
       var dialogflowRequest = ParseProtobufRequest<WebhookRequest>();
       ...
        var jsonResponse = dialogflowResponse.ToString();
        return new ContentResult { Content = jsonResponse, ContentType = "application/json" }; ;
    }

    private T ParseProtobufRequest<T>() where T : Google.Protobuf.IMessage, new()
    {
        // parse ProtoBuf (not 'normal' json) with unknown fields, else it may not bind ProtoBuf correctly
        // https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/2425 "ask the Protobuf code to parse the result"
        string requestBody;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var parser = new Google.Protobuf.JsonParser(JsonParser.Settings.Default.WithIgnoreUnknownFields(true));
        var typedRequest = parser.Parse<T>(requestBody);
        return typedRequest;
    }
```

BTW: This 'ProtoBuf-json' is also the reason to use `WebhookResponse.ToString()` which in turn uses `Google.Protobuf.JsonFormatter.ToDiagnosticString`.

## Microsoft's BotBuilder

Microsoft's BotBuilder packages and [Visual Studio template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.BotBuilderV3).
I havent't used it yet, but expect approximately the same code?

## Hand written proprietary code

A simple example of incoming request code (called an NLU-Response by Google) is provided by Madoka Chiyoda ([Chomado](https://www.slideshare.net/chomado)) at [Github](https://github.com/chomado/GoogleHomeHack/blob/master/GoogleHome.cs).  The incoming call is simply parsed to her [DialogFlowResponseModel](https://github.com/chomado/GoogleHomeHack/blob/master/Models/DialogFlowResponseModel.cs):

```
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([...]HttpRequestMessage req, [...]CloudBlockBlob mp3Out, TraceWriter log)
        ...
        var data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<Models.DialogFlowResponseModel>();
```

## Gactions

If you plan to work *without* DialogFlow later on, please note that the interface for Gactions differs significantly from the interface with DialogFlow.
The json-parameters and return-values have some overlap, but nothing gaining you any programming time (probably loosing some time by starting 'over').

However, starting with DialogFlow may gain you some quick dialog-experience (e.g. question & answer design/prototyping).
And the DialogFlow-API does have a NuGet package, where the Gactions-interface does not have a NuGet-package [just yet](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1213).

Comment: No such package available anymore

Comment: @Sana, Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.v2 1.0.0-beta02 is still available, and the link is also still valid. As implied by "Beta" and "presently in preview", you can see it if you also check the NuGet-prereleases.  
So I will consider your comment and downvote a question, and the answer is: you can see prereleases in the NuGet-GUI (VS2017) if you check the checkbox to "Include prereleases".  In the NuGet Command-Line Interface you can add a `-prerelease` switch for the same purpose.

Comment: @Sana, FWIW, I just happened to notice [Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.v2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.v2/) is out of beta, and 1.1.0 is available.  (I haven't used it in a while though.)