# Making DialogFlow v2 DetectIntent Calls w/ C# (including input context)

Tags: c#, google-api, dialogflow-es

So I finally figured out a way to successfully make detect intent calls and provide an input context.  My question is whether or not this is the **CORRECT** ***(or best)*** way to do it:

*(And yes, I know you can just call DetectIntent(agent, session, query) but I have to provide a input context(s) depending on the request)*

```
var query = new QueryInput
    {
    Text = new TextInput
    {
        Text = model.Content,
        LanguageCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Language) ? "en-us" : model.Language,
    }
};

var commonContext = new global::Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.Context
{
    ContextName = new ContextName(agent, model.sessionId, "my-input-context-data"),
    LifespanCount = 3,
    Parameters = new Struct
    {
        Fields = {
            { "Source", Value.ForString(model.Source) },
            { "UserId" , Value.ForString(model.UserId.ToString())},
            { "Name" , Value.ForString(model.FirstName)}
        }
    }
};      

var request = new DetectIntentRequest
{
    SessionAsSessionName = new SessionName(agent, model.sessionId),
    QueryParams = new QueryParameters
    {
        GeoLocation = new LatLng {Latitude = model.Latitude, Longitude = model.Longitude},
        TimeZone = model.TimeZone ?? "MST"
    },
    QueryInput = query
};
request.QueryParams.Contexts.Add(commonContext);


// ------------

var creds = GetGoogleCredentials("myCredentials.json");
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(SessionsClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, creds.ToChannelCredentials());
var client = SessionsClient.Create(channel);

var response = client.DetectIntent(request);

channel.ShutdownAsync();

return response;
```

*Note: I included the explicit `ShutDownAsync` (it's not in an async call) because I was getting some file locking issues when attempting to re-deploy the WebAPI project (and only after having executed this code).*

Thanks
Chris

**Updated 4/25:**  The most basic way I use this is to integrate the user's name into intent responses:
[image: Intent response example]

It can also be read from within the webhook/inline fulfillment index.js:

```
const name = request.body.queryResult && request.body.queryResult.outputContexts && request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.Name
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar. Do you mind sharing some screenshot for dialogflow for me to understand how you use the context parameters and the other query parameters like "GeoLocation" in your intent.

Comment: @RemyBurney The most basic way I'm using it is to add the user's name in the intent responses.