# Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: ETag in message

Tags: c#, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to send a repsonse from my webapp back to dialogflow but get the following error

> "Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response:
>   Cannot find field: ETag in message
>   google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse."

This is my code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Index(GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookRequest obj)
    {
        var response = new GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse();
        response.FulfillmentText = "Hello world";
        var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        return output; ;
    }
}
```

this is the json I return

```
{  
   "followupEventInput":null,
   "fulfillmentMessages":null,
   "fulfillmentText":"lee",
   "outputContexts":null,
   "payload":null,
   "source":null,
   "ETag":null
}
```

Any ideas? I'm using using

> Google.Apis.Dialogflow.v2.Data;

Comment: [This looks like a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242125/google-assistant-dialogflow-api-v2-webhook-etag-error) but the package data may have changed since the answer was written.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1234

Comment: Thanks all, using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 instead works :)